# Physical interpretation of Projection matrix operations $PAP$ and $(I-P)A(I-P)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I know that a Projection matrix ($P$) projects a vector onto the column space of another matrix, say $B$ ( $P$ being formed from $B$, $P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$). And $(I-P)$ projects a vector onto the null space of $B^T$. So, if we apply a projection matrix $P$ to another matrix (say, $A$), then the operation $PA$ should project all the vectors in the column space of $A$ to the column space of $B$ (I hope this interpretation is correct). Similarly, the projection should be onto the null space of $B^T$, if the operation is $(I-P)A$. But what happens if we apply the same projection matrix from the right-hand side to the obtained projections (meaning the operations $PAP$ and $(I-P)A(I-P)$)? These kind of operations have been used in quantum chemistry. Thank you.

Comment: In three dimensiona, think of $P$ as a projection onto a plane. If you look at the plane from the top, an move points around with $A$, you will see points of the plane moving around. This movement on the plane is described by $PAP$ (or rather $PA$, since we only look at points already in the plane).

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I am not sure if I understood the movement analogy that you gave. It would be great if you can elaborate on that. More importantly, is $PA$ same as $PAP$ ?  Will the eigenvalues of $PA$ and $PAP$ be the same ?

Comment: The eigenvalues of $PA$ and $PAP$ need not be the same (eg $P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$). I like to think of matrices as linear transformations (because I have my operator algebraist biases), so projections are "pushing" points of the vector space onto a subspace, while general transformations (described by $A$) will move points in some more arbitrary way.(cont..)

Comment: When we start and end a product (composition) with $P$, we are effectivelly ignoring all points of the vector space which are orthogonal to the subspace in question, and another way to do it , in the case of a plane in $3$-dimensional space, is to look at it from the top.